# Prevent a table cell from making table wider

Tags: html, css

I have this table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Important</td><td>Content</td><td>of</td><td>dynamic</td><td>length</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=5>This is a help text that should not make the table wider than the above row would ordinarily do. I want to wrap the text and just take as many lines as needed</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to make sure that the second row never causes the table to grow wider (except in the case of extremely long words, which is acceptable) than the table would be with just the first row?

Preferrably without JS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3gjsdpw/)

Clarification: The table is correct when the viewport is narrower than the first table row (then the second row is equal in width as the first row).

What I want is that the table always looks like that, even when the viewport is wider than that. (Currently it expands the table to ridiculous proportions on large screens)

Comment: Just specify the width you want in your table through CSS

Comment: If you want the table including the second row to be as wide as the table with only the first row, doesn't that mean the second row would need a width of `0`?

Comment: @Bardo: The first row has a dynamic content, which means that the width is unknown in the code.

Comment: @TheThirdMan: Tried that, doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/o3gjsdpw/

Comment: @Robby75 use percentages, you don't know how much info are you going to display, but surely your layout design know the maximum space you want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im my example below I added a class "x" to that `td` in the second row (the one with `colspan=5`). I defined it as

```
.x {
  max-width: 20px;
  }
```

This does what you want: It keeps the width of the table as wide as the other 5 cells above it need (ca. 240px):

```css
.x {
  max-width: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Important</td><td>Content</td><td>of</td><td>dynamic</td><td>length</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="x" colspan=5>This is a help text that should not make the table wider than the above row would ordinarily do. I want to wrap the text and just take as many lines as needed</td>
</tr>
</table>
```